# Cannot submit form data to DatoCMS using Gatsby.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, gatsby

I am submitting form data using this:

```js
const { SiteClient } = require("datocms-client")
const client = new SiteClient("APIKEYREMOVED")
export default async function createRecord(fields) {
  console.log('@submit function ',fields)
  const record = await client.items.create(fields)
  console.log(record)
}
```

This is the error information, but I can't make heads or tails of it.

[image: Gatsby form submit error]

The form's handle submit function successfully call createRecord() from the form page. So, problem would seem to be from the snippet provided.

I sourced said snippet from here: [DatoCMS create record simple example](https://www.datocms.com/docs/content-management-api/resources/item/create#basic-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the relationship between your form and the content model in DatoCMS. According to the docs:

> Suppose our project contains a "Dog" model (ID: 1234, API key: dog) with the >following fields:
>
> | Field API Key | Field Type |
> | --- | --- |
> | name | Single-line String |
> | breed | Single-line String |
> | description | Multiple-paragraph text |
> | age | Integer |
>
> ```
> const { SiteClient } = require("datocms-client");
> const client = new SiteClient("YOUR-API-TOKEN");
> async function createRecord() {
>   const record = await client.items.create({
>     itemType: "1234", // model ID
>     name: "Gigio",
>     breed: "Labrador",
>     description: "Very friendly and calm.\nI love it.",
>     age: 4,
>   });
>   console.log(record);
> }
> createRecord();
> ```

In your case, it seems that you are not matching the `itemType`, which is the model ID, as the promise output suggests in your `console.log`.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer. I completely overlooked needing to tell the client what the model ID is. To clarify it was the numerical ID provided in DatoCMS in the top right of the model info window in light gray, not the system model name.